# How can I validate the Date from a Angular material Datepicker based on another Datepicker

Tags: angular, validation, dynamic, datepicker

I have 2 Angular Material Datepickers and want to implement the following validation:
-The date of the first datepicker has to be the min-date of the 2nd one

Here are my datepickers

```
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy" [style.width.%]="45">
  <mat-label>Phasenbeginn</mat-label>
  <input matInput  placeholder="Beginn" [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="pStart">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>                                   
          
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy" [style.width.%]="45">
  <mat-label>Phasenende</mat-label>
  <input matInput  placeholder="Ende" [matDatepicker]="picker2" formControlName="pEnd">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
 </mat-form-field>
```

On the material documentation they say, that you can add a "[min] = minDate" binding to the input, but I think this is only used for static dates, saved in a variable.

I want to do something like this, on the 2nd picker

```
<input matInput [min]="picker.value" placeholder="Ende" [matDatepicker]="picker2" formControlName="pEnd">
```

Comment: You can define a custom validator: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before attempting a custom validator, you should be able to do this with a property binding to the `[min]` property. Try this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy" [style.width.%]="45">
  <mat-label>Phasenbeginn</mat-label>
  <input matInput [max]="pEnd.value" placeholder="Beginn" [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="pStart">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>                                   
          
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy" [style.width.%]="45">
  <mat-label>Phasenende</mat-label>
  <input matInput [min]="pStart.value" placeholder="Ende" [matDatepicker]="picker2" formControlName="pEnd">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
 </mat-form-field>
```

The above code does assume that `pStart` and `pEnd` are properly implemented formControls in a formGroup. `formControlName` is not usable outside of a `<form>` with a defined `[formGroup]`.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, I tried it but get the following error: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Make sure you are creating the pStart and pEnd FormControls in your TS file and that they are always defined. If you are using a FormGroup you may need to replace `pStart.value` with `[FormGroup_name].controls.pStart.value` and same with `pEnd`.

Comment: Thank you very much. The string was this.projectForm.controls['phases'].value[i].pStart